# Ember-CLI build results in segmentation fault

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Using ember-cli, in a fairly new ember project i'm getting a 'segmentation fault when trying to build for the production environment.

```
Building..[1]    41300 segmentation fault  ember build --environment=production
```

or

```
Building..%
```

The ember-cli build task has no verbose setting, so I'm kind of at a loss for how to debug this problem.

I did setup a new project, and tried installing the same dependencies my real project is using, and it built just fine.

Short of slowly migrating things into a new project and building intermittently to see if/when if breaks, is there anything I can do to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution. It turns out that there were some corrupted images  and non-image files in the assets/images folder causing this fault.

Many of the conversations I was finding relating to a ember build seg fault were pointing towards SASS compilation, but it turns out that wasn't at all the case.

The method I used to debug was simply to create a new project, and then file by file copy in my existing project, building at every step. This way I was able to rule out everything including the SASS compilation.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Same here (on linux by chance?) but just deleted three images ember had in the dist folder. Then it built fine.

```
unnamed.png
passed.png
failed.png
```